# Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end; When testing NextJS API Routes with Jest

Tags: next.js, jestjs, node-modules, supertest

I want to unit test using Jest the following NextJS API endpoint:

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  await handleCors(req, res, [httpMethods.POST]);

  if (req.method === httpMethods.POST) {
    await requireUsernamePasswordLogin(req, res);

    return res;
  }
  return res.status(405).end();
}
```

Some middleware functions are also involved in this implementation, for example this is the `requireUsernamePasswordLogin` middleware:

```js
export async function requireUsernamePasswordLogin(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    
    // check if email and password are not empty
    if (!email || !password) {
      reject(res.status(400).json({ responseId: EMPTY_DATA_FIELD }));
      return;
    }

    // check if email is in a valid format
    if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
      reject(res.status(400).json({ responseId: INVALID_EMAIL }));
      return;
    }

    // authenticate using passport localStrategy
    passport.authenticate(localStrategy, { session: false }, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(res.status(403).json({ responseId: err }));
      }

      return resolve(
        res.status(200).json({
          responseId: SUCCESSFUL,
          token,
        }),
      );
    })(req, res);
  });
}
```

And the test that I created using Jest looks like this:

```js
import { createServer, RequestListener } from 'http';
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import request from 'supertest';
import { apiResolver } from 'next/dist/server/api-utils/node';
import handler from '../../../pages/api/auth/login';

const testClient = (handler: NextApiHandler) => {
  const listener: RequestListener = (req, res) => {
    return apiResolver(
      req,
      res,
      undefined,
      handler,
      {
        previewModeEncryptionKey: '',
        previewModeId: '',
        previewModeSigningKey: '',
      },
      false,
    );
  };

  return request(createServer(listener));
};

describe('/api/auth/login', () => {
  it('user not existing', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const requestBody = {
      email: 'test-user@gmail.com',
      password: 'test_password',
      preferredLanguage: 'en',
    };
    const client = testClient(handler);

    // Act
    let response = await client.post('/api/auth/login').send(requestBody);

    // Assert
    expect(response.text).toEqual('{"responseId":"user_not_existing"}');
    expect(response.status).toBe(403);
  });
}
```

The error output that I get when I run `npm run test:watch`:

```bash
    FAIL  __tests__/api/auth/auth.login.test.ts
      ● Console
    
        console.log
          Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
    
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
    
        console.log
          Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
    
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
    
        console.log
          Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
    
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
    
        console.log
          Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "email", "password", "confirmed_on", "preferred_language" FROM "users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."email" ILIKE 'test-user@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;
    
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
    
        console.log
          Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
    
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
    
        console.error
          undefined
    
          at error (../node_modules/next/server/api-utils/node.ts:545:15)
    
      ● /api/auth/login › user not existing
    
        Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    
          at ServerResponse.apply [as end] (../node_modules/next/server/api-utils/node.ts:488:19)
          at Object.end [as sendError] (../node_modules/next/server/api-utils/index.ts:180:7)
          at apiResolver (../node_modules/next/server/api-utils/node.ts:549:54)
    
    
      ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
        Attempted to log "Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result".
    
          94 |           });
          95 |
        > 96 |         await this.cmsDatabase
             |         ^
          97 |           .authenticate()
          98 |           .then(() => {
          99 |             process.stdout.write('DB: cms database connected!\n');
    
          at console.log (../node_modules/@jest/console/build/BufferedConsole.js:156:10)
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
          at Query._logQuery (../node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/abstract/query.js:376:22)
          at Query.run (../node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/postgres/query.js:73:27)
          at ../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:649:28
          at Sequelize.authenticate (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:971:5)
          at src/shared/databaseConnection.repository.ts:96:9
    
    
      ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
        Attempted to log "Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result".
    
          94 |           });
          95 |
        > 96 |         await this.cmsDatabase
             |         ^
          97 |           .authenticate()
          98 |           .then(() => {
          99 |             process.stdout.write('DB: cms database connected!\n');
    
          at console.log (../node_modules/@jest/console/build/BufferedConsole.js:156:10)
          at Sequelize.log (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:1279:15)
          at Query._logQuery (../node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/abstract/query.js:376:22)
          at Query.run (../node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/postgres/query.js:73:27)
          at ../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:649:28
          at Sequelize.authenticate (../node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:971:5)
          at src/shared/databaseConnection.repository.ts:96:9
```

The test should throw a 403 status code with a response that the user does not exist.
I don't know where the issue comes from, is it because the test's assertions are created wrongly? Or do I need to mock the user entry or something else? I couldn't find any source or something useful that would point me in the right direction to at least know how to create one proper unit test for an API endpoint considering the above implementations.
Any documentation source or GitHub repo that can help me solve this would be appreciated.